# How to check equality with nodes from an earlier part of query in Gremlin?

Tags: gremlin

Consider the following graph:

[image]

I want to find all the pairs of people who have a `FOLLOWS` relationship between them and have reviewed the same movie. In Cypher, I would do the following:

```
MATCH (p:Person) -[:REVIEWED]-> (m:Movie)
MATCH (p) -[:FOLLOWS]-> (p2:Person)
MATCH (p2) -[:REVIEWED]-> (m)
RETURN p, p2, m
```

What I have so far in Gremlin:

```
g.V().hasLabel('person').as('p')
 .out('REVIEWED').as('m')
 .in('REVIEWED').as('p2')
 .where(in('FOLLOWS').is(select('p')))   // this doesn't work
 .select('p', 'm', 'p2')
```

But this doesn't work. How can I get achieve this in Gremlin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually very close. Try this

```java
g.V().hasLabel('person').as('p')
 .out('REVIEWED').as('m')
 .in('REVIEWED').as('p2')
 .where(in('FOLLOWS').as('p'))  
 .select('p', 'm', 'p2')
```

We can test the query using this simple graph

```java
g.addV('Person').property('name','P1').as('p1').
  addV('Person').property('name','P2').as('p2').
  addV('Person').property('name','P3').as('p3').
  addV('Movie').property('name','Shrek').as('m1').
  addE('REVIEWED').from('p1').to('m1').
  addE('REVIEWED').from('p2').to('m1').
  addE('REVIEWED').from('p3').to('m1').
  addE('FOLLOWS').from('p1').to('p3')
```

and we can see that it works using the Gremlin Console

```java
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('Person').as('p').
......1>       out('REVIEWED').as('m').
......2>       in('REVIEWED').as('p2').
......3>       where(__.in('FOLLOWS').as('p')).
......4>       select('p', 'm', 'p2').by('name')

==>[p:P1,m:Shrek,p2:P3]
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. I thought underscores were used to avoid gremlin functionality conflicting with language built-ins. If that's the case, can you tell me why underscores are needed when using the console?

Comment: The Gremlin Console sits on top of the Groovy Console - it's to avoid reserved word conflicts with Groovy (as Groovy will try to parse what is entered)

Comment: @KelvinLawrence I tried this myself and it works (thank you!) .  Does this also imply that the "as" step will never overwrite a previous step?  For instance, once you use `.as("key")` a future step that tries to set `.as("key")` to a different vertex won't overwrite which vertex that "key" refers to?    It's a bit distressing to me because I don't see anything in the documentation that explains how it works.

Comment: I'm not sure how well this is going to format as a comment, but in reality it will be creating a list known as `a`. For example `gremlin> g.addV('a').as('a').addV('b').as('a').select(all,'a')
==>[v[61286],v[61287]]    ` I do cover it a bit here https://kelvinlawrence.net/book/PracticalGremlin.html#multias

Comment: @KelvinLawrence I'm sorry to ask again. I'm still not sure I get how `where(in('FOLLOWS').as('p')` works. It looks like that where clause would pass if there we any 'FOLLOWS' edge incoming to the vertex. Does the `.as('p')` have something built in to not return in a where clause if 'p' isn't equal to its previous value?  This is a question that I asked today that is similar, and was the issue I was trying to solve when I found this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73325404/gremlin-continue-traversal-only-if-2-vertices-are-not-the-same/73325811#73325811

Comment: Ah OK - that is a special case of `as`. Read that `as` as `is the thing named as p`. It's similar to the way `as` gets overloaded in the `match` step. This allows you to pretty much write a declarative `match` like query just using a `where` step.