# Gremlin continue traversal only if 2 vertices are not the same

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune

I have a query which looks at 2 different vertices and I want to stop traversing if they don't both roll up to the same root ancestor via a path of "contains" edges.

```
 g.V('node1')
  .until(hasLabel('root')).repeat(in('contains')).as('node1Root')
  .V('node2')
  .until(hasLabel('root')).repeat(in('contains')).as('node2Root')
  //FILTER|WHERE clause
```

I'd like to confirm that node1Root and node2root are the same vertex before continuing the traversal, but for the life of me I cannot figure out how to do this.

I've tried the following:

```
 g.V('node1')
  .until(hasLabel('root')).repeat(in('contains')).as('node1Root')
  .V('node2')
  .until(hasLabel('root')).repeat(in('contains')).as('node2Root')
  //.where('node1Root', P.eq('node2Root')
  //.where(select("node1Root").is(P.eq("node2Root")))
  //.where(select("node1Root").is("node2Root"))
```

What's interesting is that the following query *does* work to filter appropriately.

```
g.V('node1').as('1')
 .V('node2').as('2')
 .where('1', P.eq('2'))
```

I'm not sure if there's something up with the until/repeat that screws it up or if I'm just doing something blatantly wrong.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Any comments for this idea ? You can apply dfs algo and store index start and end time as range indexes. Then do topological sorting by normal search queries.

Answer (score 0):

I found [How to check equality with nodes from an earlier part of query in Gremlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70577424/how-to-check-equality-with-nodes-from-an-earlier-part-of-query-in-gremlin)

and it seems like you use "as" with the same key as the previous "as" and if they match its considered equal.

So here's the winner (I think):

```
 g.V('node1')
.until(hasLabel('root')).repeat(in('contains')).as('node1Root')
.V('node2')
.until(hasLabel('root')).repeat(in('contains')).as('node2Root')
.where(select('node1Root').as('node2Root')
//.not(select('node1Root').as('node2Root')) //OR this to determine they aren't the same
//continue traversal
```

I also found that my original issue was that the .until().repeat() steps could return a LIST, but in my case I know that my graph model will always return a single 'root' so to make it work, I can use 'unfold'

```
 g.V('node1')
 .until(hasLabel('root')).repeat(in('contains')).unfold().as('node1Root')
 .V('node2')
 .until(hasLabel('root')).repeat(in('contains')).unfold().as('node2Root')
 .where('node1Root', P.eq('node2Root')
```

I think I'll be going with the second solution because I'm much more confident in it, unless I hear otherwise.

Comment: This will not work. `repeat` step do not return array.

Comment: check this out unfold is not working . https://gremlify.com/22xjqx93z9w/1

Comment: Just checking in to see if you git everything working. If not, happy to help with a few more suggestions.

Comment: I just posted a link made by gremlify. That is a nice playground for gremlin. Here you can test your queries. I was pointing out that unfold will not work like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this gremlin query

```
g.V(node1-id)
.map(until(hasLabel('root')).repeat(in().aggregate('x')).cap('x')).as("array")
 .V(node2-id)
  .until(
     
      as("i").select("array").unfold().as("j")
      .where("i", eq("j"))
      
      ).repeat(in())
```

Here we are putting all the vertices in path to root from node1 in an array, and secondly we are checking existence of node in array.

this query can only work with traversal with only one iteration because `aggregate` step collect to a global variable to traversal that means it will be same array for every iteration. To fix this If you are doing this on jvm do use lamda/groovy closures

```
g.V(node-start-id-1,node-start-id-2)
.map(
    { x->
    
    var v = x.get()
    var g =  getGraph().get().traversal();
    g.V(v.id())until(hasLabel('root')).repeat(in().aggregate('x')).cap('x')).next()
    }
)
.as("array")
 .V(node2-id)
  .until(

      as("i").select("array").unfold().as("j")
      .where("i", eq("j"))

      ).repeat(in())
```

Comment: You can try this query quickly here https://gremlify.com/a2nm1q2nuq/4

Comment: I tend to never recommend use of closures as a lot of graph stores do not support the injection of arbitrary code into queries.

Comment: Yes, that's there I just wrote that code to give a idea to designer on how they can innovate to add custom dsl if they have that option with like they can do with janusgraph, hugegraph, other tinkepop supported self hosted dbs.

Comment: @KelvinLawrence do you have any ideas for aggregate alterative that can work per iteration basis ? just like fold unfold group under local ?